# Can a set be a subset of its own power set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this statement valid? This is a part of an exercise question in the book *How to prove it*.

$$
A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)
$$

This is my understanding: For $A \subseteq B$ to be valid, the types of elements in $A$ must match those in $B$ according to the definition $\forall x \in A (x \in B)$.

Comment: Yes, a set with that property is called transitive.  All ordinals are transitive.  All stages of the von-Neumann hierarchy are transitive.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2197404/is-a-a-proper-set-of-its-power-set) and its answers.

Comment: Observe that $\emptyset\subset A$ for *all* $A$; therefore _a fortiori_ $\emptyset\subset \mathcal P(\emptyset)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Consider $\emptyset$ for example.

Comment: Refining my question - is that statement still valid for non empty sets?

Comment: Still, yes. Consider $\{ \emptyset \} \subseteq \mathcal{P} (\{ \emptyset \}) = \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}$.

Comment: Wow, that's neat. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

First, the definition of inclusion is:
\begin{equation}
A \subseteq B \leftrightarrow [\forall x(x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)]
\end{equation}
This is "different" from the definition that you give.

**Edit**: the sentence $\forall x (x \in A \rightarrow P(x))$ for some formula $P$ in the language is equivalent to $\forall x \in A (P(x))$ due to bounded quantifiers.

Now as John Doe said, you can consider transitive sets.

We define for any set $a$, the successor $a^+$ by
\begin{equation}
a^+ = a \cup \lbrace a \rbrace
\end{equation}
Now we say that a set $A$ is transitive iff:
\begin{align}
\forall a \forall x (x \in a \wedge a \in A \rightarrow x\in A)
\end{align}

Now is easy to prove that if $A$ is any set then the next sentences are equivalent:
\begin{align}
\text{i) } & A \text{ is transitive} \\
\text{ii) }& \bigcup A \subseteq A \\
\text{iii) }& A \subseteq P(A) \\
\text{iv) }& \bigcup A^+ = A
\end{align}

Comment: $\forall x (x \in A \implies x \in B)$ can be written concisely as $\forall x \in A (x \in B)$, according to my textbook.

Comment: You're right. I didn't know about bounded quantifiers. Although I had to do some operations to arrive at the equivalence, the arguments in the book were not enough for me. I just edited my answer